# Regex Expression shouldn't start with numberic number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the "username" field of form. My scenario are following

1) username shouldn't start with numeric character (0-9)
2) username can have numeric character in between like "Smith9Rockz"
3) username can't start with any special character.

I just found this expression which is not working for my condition

```
 var validaddress = /^[0-9].*$/;
```

Guide me correct regex expression in Javascript. how can i achieve my desired result?

Comment: Why would you disallow numbers in usernames?

Comment: Which characters should the string contain?

Comment: @Pointy please read my scenario carefully. i mentioned that my username shouldn't start with number but it can have number in between of username

Comment: Why shouldn't it start with a number? Why is that a problem?

Comment: @FahadSubzwari: When you say the first character shouldn't allow digits and special characters, that implies a specific set that you want to exclude, with everything else being allowed. If you want to include only a specific set of characters at the start, then it's much simpler to say that the first character must be a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
^[[:alpha:]].*
```

**Explanation**:

It accepts usernames which start (^) with an alphabetic character (so, neither number nor special character) and after that they have any number/special character (.*).

If you want to avoid special char in between you should use:

```
^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*
```

where `[:alnum:]` search for alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

This should work according to your description. The character set at the start excludes numbers and a bunch of special characters, which you can complete. Then after that, it's just letters and numbers.

```
var re = /^[^0-9#$%&*()-][0-9a-z]*$/i
```

If for the first character, you meant it must be a letter, then that's simpler.

```
var re = /^[a-z][0-9a-z]*$/i
```

Comment: Your second solution will not accept uppercase alphabetic characters as first character

Comment: @Neb: Yes it does.

Comment: @Neb: Yes, just test it and you'll see. `[a-Z]` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: You're right, i mean [A-z], from char A=65 to char z=122. Your expression matches username starting with a char in between a=97 to z=122. See https://regexr.com/

Comment: @Neb `.../i` (the `i` at the end) makes the patter case insensitive.

Comment: @Neb: All you really needed to do was test it to see that it works. Using `[A-z]` is incorrect because it allows characters from `0x5B` to `0x60`, so it would allow square brackets, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var re = /^[a-zA-Z].+$/;
var valid_username = 'Some1ok!';
var invalid_username = '1some1!';

re.test(valid_username); // true
re.test(invalid_username); // false
```